# When scripting an auto responding in php how can you change the from email section?

Tags: php, phpmailer

firstly I am not overly knowledgeable in PHP. I will try to explain with the understanding that the PHP on my site was written by a friend for me in college so I only understand small bits of it. Anyhow, everything is working great, I was just wondering right now when the auto-reply is received it is from nf.theamitybladecom@boscustweb2204.eigbox.net which kind of bugs me. theamitybladecom is, of course, a reference to my site name. I was hoping I could tweak it to say from noreply@theamityblade.com or something. Anyways, this is the code I have so far, and forgive me for removing a few sensitive entries. Hopefully, you understand what I strive to do and that it is an easy alteration to my code. I can't handle complex PHP basically at all so please explain it in newbie terms. Any help you can offer would be greatly appreciated. Thanks,
Black_Lightning

```
    <?php
        /* Verify captcha from google */
        function verify_captcha($response) {
            $url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify';
            $curl = curl_init();
            $captcha_verify_url = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify";
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL,$captcha_verify_url);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "secret=captchaSecretKey&response=".$response);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            $verify = curl_exec ($curl);
            curl_close ($curl);

            $captcha_success=json_decode($verify);
            if ($captcha_success->success==true) {
                return true;
            } else{
                return false;
            }
        }

    $action=$_REQUEST['action'];
    $show_form = true;
    if ($action!="")    /* display the contact form */
        {
            $name=$_POST['name'];
            $email=$_POST['email'];
            $message=$_POST['message'];
            $response = $_POST["g-recaptcha-response"];

            //check if the captcha is valid or not
            if (verify_captcha($response)) {
                $subject="New Message for me!";
                mail("example@mysite.com",$subject,$message,"From: $email \n");
                echo "Email sent!!";
                $show_form = false;
            } else if ($captcha_success->success==false) {
                $show_form = true;
            }
        }
    ?>
    <?php if($show_form) { ?>
        <form  id="form" class="contact-form" action="" onSubmit="return checkValid()"method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          <input type="hidden" name="action" value="submit" />
          <span id="blue-text">Your name:<br>
        <input id="name" name="name" type="text" value="" size="50"/>
        <br>
        Your email:<br>
        <input id="email" name="email" type="text" value="" size="50"/><br>
        Your message:<br>
        </span>
          <textarea id="message" name="message" wrap="hard" rows="10" cols="49" ></textarea>
          <br>
        <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="captchaSiteKey"></div>
        <input type="submit" value="Send"/>
        </form>
        <?php
        } 
        /* Prepare autoresponder subject */
    $respond_subject = "Thank you for contacting me!";

    /* Prepare autoresponder message */
    $respond_message = "Hello!

    Thank you for contacting me! I will get back to you
    as soon as possible!

    Yours sincerely,

   My Name
    www.mysite.com
    ";

    /* Send the message using mail() function */
    mail($email, $respond_subject, $respond_message);
    ?>
    <script>
        function checkValid()
        {
            var name = document.getElementById("name");
            var email = document.getElementById("email");
            var message = document.getElementById("message");
            var firstError = null;

            var errorMessage = "";
            if (name.value == "")
            {
                errorMessage += "Please enter your name! \n";
                if (firstError == null)
                {
                    firstError = name;
                }
            }
            if (email.value == "")
            {
                errorMessage += "Please enter your email! \n";
                if (firstError == null)
                {
                    firstError = email;
                }
            }
            if (message.value == "")
            {
                errorMessage += "Please enter your message! \n";
                if (firstError == null)
                {
                    firstError = message;
                }
            }

            if (errorMessage != "")
            {
                alert(errorMessage);
                firstError.focus();
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is currently trying to use the submitter's email address as the from address:

```
mail("example@mysite.com",$subject,$message,"From: $email \n");
```

Don't do that; it's forgery and will either be prevented from working altogether, or result in your messages being spam-filtered or bounced. Set it as a reply-to header instead:

```
mail("example@mysite.com", $subject, $message, "Reply-to: $email \n");
```

This code is vulnerable to header injection attacks as no filtering is applied to `$_POST['email']` before it is used as a message header. Overall, avoid using the mail function altogether; it's inherently unsafe. Use a library like PHPMailer (that you tagged this question with) and send using SMTP to localhost, which is both faster and safer. See [PHPMailer's contact form example](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/contactform.phps).

Comment: thanks for your reply. Since I am not good with php It'll probably be best to not have an auto response to avoid the header injection whatever that is. Again, thanks for showing me where I went wrong in the code though.